# Почему выдача в poedit и через wordpress функции значительно различается?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на `WordPress`, используя **HTTP API** которого, получаю данные с *внешнего API*.

(запрос, авторизованный с помощью токена)

```
$response = wp_remote_get($url,array(
     'headers' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.BEARER_TOKEN
));
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
print_r($body);
```

Но, как оказалось, введя тот же url с параметрами в **ПО POSTMAN**, результатов на выходе в нём в 40+ раз больше. В чём может быть причина расхождений и куда стоит копать?

**UPD** Запрос вида

https://site?country=usa&datefrom=2023-03-11&dateto=2023-03-18

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Каке параметры poedit? Какое отношение poedit имеет к внешнему API?

Comment: @KAGG Design с ПО ошибся, `postman` конечно. Параметры обновил в вопросе

Comment: @Вася запрос прям один в один такой же? Может лимиты есть где-то? Тут только самому копаться на каждом шаге

Comment: Попробуйте, просто через AJAX_API WP сделать этот же запрос... возможно ограничения в WP или на сервере установлены.

Comment: Разница тут возможно  в разных IP адресах с которых делаются запросы. Возможно API по разному реагирует на разные регионы, а может быть и страны откуда приел запрос.

Comment: @DaemonHK да, 1 в 1. Выборка, которая отдаётся через `php` присутствует в результатах postmana.
Откуда предложите шагать? Я не вижу первого шага куда копать..

Comment: @BlackStar1991 к сожалению, сервер запрещает ajax запросы..

Comment: @Вася сажайте задачу на крон тогда